Can I use a header (include) file licensed as GPLv2 only in GPLv3 project?
To be brief, I am working on a big C project, which I want to license under GPLv3.
I need some compiler-specific attribute macros, and I find include/linux/compiler_attributes.h from Linux kernel source as something really fitting my needs. I am tempted to use this header in my project, but I see it is covered by GPL-2.0 at the top.
So if I were to, say, follow my temptation and include this:

Can I even do this with a GPLv3 project?
Do I have to include a notice that this file comes from Linux source?
And if I were to not include the exact copy, but rewrite those macros myself (which I can't see not being very similar to the Linux one), could any licensing issues arise with their contents being quite close to each other?

I mean, those are just a set of #define directives with references to public docs, there is no way to make it something other than what is written in the original header, right?
I am looking forward to understand where exactly does GPL put its' boundaries, and how exactly can I work with the code licensed under it.

Is there a technical reason you need to use the same exact defines? For example, I see from that file that linux is using in place of the official GCC attribute syntax __attribute__((__aligned__(x))), the peculiar name __aligned(x), a name introduced by two underscores. If the average-Joe or Jill programmer were naming a shortcut for this for herself, she would probably just call it ALIGNED(x) in her project, in keeping with the semi-standard C programming practice of naming macros ALL-CAPS and avoiding leading underscores.

@Brandin I am used to having macros exactly like this for stuff which is typically in lowercase, e.g. keyword-like macros except ifs. So it's really a matter of preference.
The thing is, I thought of that Linux header as a good collection of macros I might need in the future, but as I got the answer that I can't really use that, I decided to read through gcc docs and cherry-pick macros, providing links for gcc/clang docs like Linux does and keeping the same macro style just because I like it. The result, as you can guess, is basically the same with less macros and few tweaks, if you compare.

You're copying a big chunk of code from a third-party codebase into your own.  From a copyright standpoint, the starting position is that your work is now a derivative of the third-party code.  Such re-use is either permitted by the licence, in which case there may be associated obligations, or it's a copyright violation.
In this case, the original is licensed under GPLv2 (the use of v2-only is a bit of a cause célèbre in the kernel community, so it's unlikely that you'll get permission to relicense it).  GPLv2 code is not compatible with GPLv3 code, so (1) no, you can't do this with a GPLv3 project.
(2) If you were to reuse that code, you'd have to honour all of the obligations of GPLv2, which includes retaining all pre-existing copyright notices.
(3) You're right that one defence against an allegation of copyright infringement is "I created this file myself from scratch, and it's only similar to your copyrighted file because there's really only one way to write code that does this thing".  But firstly, there's no bright-line test for that defence: you always run the risk that it fails.  Secondly, as I understand it, it doesn't apply to "I rewrote your code but I didn't rewrite it much because there's really only one way to write this code", which is what you propose.
In short, if you license your project under GPLv2 (and honour the obligations thereof) you can reuse that file to your heart's content whilst running no risk of infringement allegations.  If you don't, you can't.

"A big chunk of code" is a bit of an overstatement here. I agree that it should not be done, and that your reasoning is sound. To put it in perspective, this would be a bit like copying a list of a technical glossary found in the back of a 1000-page reference book. The glossary is 1 page (analogous to the file in question), while all of the "meat" of the work is the other 999 pages. A serious author (or a serious programmer) should write up her own glossary, in any case.

To be clear, though, copying only 1 page out of 1000 does not make it "OK" per se in a copyright perspective. The overall percentage here is not really that important to any determination. I doubt a ruling of fair use (or fair dealing) would apply here. Maybe no one would complain, but also remember that Linux has thousands of active contributors, so in theory any of them could be a stakeholder in a potential action against an alleged infringer. I.e. the simple answer is "do not do this; write your own file".

It's 421 lines of code (or was in the version I looked at), and that's way bigger than de minimis, and certainly big enough to qualify for copyright protection - hence my use of the phrase "big chunk of code".  I agree with your closing point, though!

This comment is mainly nitpicking on the wording "big chunk of code". This file is significant, to be sure, but most of its significance is in comments (creative by definition), not really what we'd consider "code" per se. The non-comments are, as the OP says, are #defines. Boring, yes, but unfortunately this is sometimes just a part of "real" C programming, as it were. I counted 44 unique definitions in this file, and I would find it pretty unlikely that another non-kernel project would need special shortcuts for all 44 of those, so that's another reason not to copy it.

Thank you for that analysis.  I'm only a sysadmin, so can't comment authoritatively on C code, but you sound very persuasive!  Nevertheless, there's no suggestion that only functional creation qualifies for copyright protection - otherwise all Disney movies would be fair game - so the lack-of-utility of 90% of the file doesn't affect its copyrightability.  I still think 400+ lines is big.  If OP had said "I plan to extract the functional elements from GPLv2 file foo.c, what are the copyright implications?" I agree that my answer might have been somewhat different!

That said, I take your point about the nitpicking, and it's a fair pick.  I suppose I mean the file is big compared to the threshold for copyright protection, not big compared to the rest of the codebase, about which you make some very good observations.

@Brandin "another non-kernel project" <- yeah, about that... I guess I should have mentioned that I am doing a kernel project?
